# @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAbout", "EditAboutPage") gives me 404 file not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

im trying to make an Edit function but its not working my `@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditAbout", "EditAboutPage")`  will not send me there i only get 404 file not found.

this is my Controller

```
public class EditAboutPageController : Controller
{
    // GET: EditAboutPage
    public ActionResult EditAbout()
    {
        var currentAboutInfo = Repository.GetLatestAbouts();
        return View(currentAboutInfo);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditAbout(EditAboutModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var about = Repository.GetLatestAbouts();
            Repository.UpdateAbouts(Repository.SetAboutValues(model, about));
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "About");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
 }
```

what is it i do wrong??

Comment: Try to debug your code...

Comment: What is your routing configuration ? Is your view has currentAboutInfo's data type as model ?

Comment: Post your view's code and the configuration of your routes

Answer (score 0):

on the method use `[HttpGet]`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditAbout()
{
    var currentAboutInfo = Repository.GetLatestAbouts();
    return View(currentAboutInfo);
}
```

Comment: No needs, it's the default attribute

Comment: [HttpGet] and others are action filters. Without one you allow any HTTP verb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this overloaded option for avoiding the ambiguity with your routing

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit","EditAbout","EditAboutPage",null,null)
```